# Scala: How to get all keys from Option[Map[String, Int]]?

Tags: scala

I have this val: `val offsets: Option[Map[String, Int]] = jsonOffsets.get(topic)`

How do I get all the keys from `offsets`? Is it `offsets[0]`, `offsets.keys` isn't working.

Comment: Since you want to access by index _(which is not common in **Scala**)_ you can do this: `offsets.fold(ifEmpty = Vector.empty)(map => map.keys.toVector)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`offsets` is an `Option`, so it may or may not contain a `Map`. Use pattern matching to handle that:

```
offsets match {
    case Some(map) => // Whatever you want to do with the map
    case None => // What should you do when there's no map?
}
```

If you don't know about options, [this](https://danielwestheide.com/blog/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type/) is a good read.

Comment: If there are values, how do we get all the keys into an array? like this?

offsets match { case Some(map) => val offSetsList = map.keys
}

Comment: Indeed, there is a `keys` method that returns an `Iterable`: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/AbstractMap.html#keys:Iterable[K]. I find I don't use the API docs much these days - I tend to rely on my IDE (IntelliJ) to tell me what methods are available.

Comment: If you are using an IDE (as you should be), you should be able to see the types of your values. Knowing the types should help you understand what's going on.